# Bootstrap - centering content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with centering the text in the card. Currently it looks like this.

[image]

I would like the description/content of the card to start in the same point (under the pink line). How do you get it?

I use bootstrap, this is my code

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img width="50" class="card-img-top" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img width="50" class="card-img-top" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a. Contrary to popular belief.</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give fix height to `card-title` so it cant be changed !!

So, the description/content of the card starts in the same point (under the pink line).

```css
.card-title {
   min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="50" class="card-img-top" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="50" class="card-img-top" src="http://d3sdoylwcs36el.cloudfront.net/VEN-virtual-enterprise-network-business-opportunities-small-fish_id799929_size485.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a. Contrary to popular belief.</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bro for that he/she need to add responsive classes to manage view of card, like col-sm-* and col-lg-*

Comment: why ? i need to include responsive manner on my answer, i don't see any question about responsiveness and in problem that not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

add `height: auto;` on your class `card-title` so it would automatically resize your container based on texts inside.

Comment: height auto not solution of that ! change or delete your answer